# Is it possible to create a new dom using select parts from another dom? Or prune away unwanted parts

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering if its possible to load a html page but only display a few select parts of it.

Two possible approaches come to mind:

1) Delete parts of the dom I'm not interested in.
However I wouldn't know what all those parts are, I'd only know the parts I'm interested in.
Is it possible to find the parts I'm interested in then remove everything else?

2) Create a new dom which has been made by extracting parts of the dom from the original.
Is it possible to somehow create this in parallel to the existing dom and make the browser switch to this new dom? Or alternatively create a html page from this new dom and then load that?

Are these crazy ideas? Any simple / alternative solutions?

Comment: All of this is possible but from the perspective of who? Who is the user in this scenario and where is the DOM modification occurring? Javascript can easily knock out DOM elements, a screen scraper with an HTML parser library can easily filter down the DOM, a UserScript/GreaseMonkey script can filter the DOM in Chrome. What layer did you want to accomplish this in?

Comment: It would be within an iOS app, its to display only portions of a page loading in a iOS page. The page could be hidden while the scraping process is occurring then made visible. The javascript execution and dom manipulation would be being controlled by the iOS app.

Comment: You dont need the browser to switch to a new dom. You would create javascript functions to activate an event such as an onclick event to display or hide the desired or undesirable content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use JavaScript/jQuery.

First you have to add the jquery library to your website as a javascript link like so.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>.
```

You would need to create a function similar to then you would put an onclick event on a link.

```
 <script>
function switch(){
$("#button").onclick(function()
{
 $(".classOfCertainElements").css("display", "none");
 $(".classOtherElements").css("display", "inline");
});

} 
</script>
<a href="" id="button">Click me</a>
```

Does that help?

Comment: And code for that might look like...? Is it a standard thing I can find with some googling?

Comment: first you have to add the jquery library to your website as a javascript link like so. <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>

Comment: @cocre8or—there are a very large number of elements whose default *display* property is not block. Setting them all to block is likely to have unexpected (and unwanted) results.

Comment: Would display inline be better? Or visibility:hidden?

Comment: @ChrisP.Bacon the jquery library is full of useful functions. [link](http://jquery.com)

Comment: @cocre8or For elements you want to unhide that you explicitly set .css('display', 'none') on, you want to eliminate that - so: .css('display', ''). If the display: none is set higher with the selector, you should instead reveal it by removing the class that causes it to be selected by the hiding selector.

Answer (score 1):

Well the two easiest ways would probably the following.

1. **Don't load the *undesirable* parts.** By this, I mean that if you know what parts you
    don't want to display then just remove them from the HTML. This isn't always an option,
    but it is certainly the best if only have a set amount of choices.
2. **Hide elements via CSS.** You can do this by setting `display: none` on an unwanted
    element.

Comment: How would I prevent the undesirable parts from being loaded?